# compiling boost based application using cron

Tags: linux, cron, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I am building some boost based application for various embedded targets. I have developed a script which can build my application with different toolchain for several targets. This script works fine when I run it from command line but if it is invoked from cron it always fails to link the object files. My application has dependency on openssl. Can anyone please give some idea? What would be the root cause of this kind of behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`cron` jobs will run with a much reduced environment. So you need to determine which environment variables (`PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc.) your compile depends on, and then reflect those variables in the shell script you're invoking from `cron`.

Comment: ok.. thanks for the response. But here I am using all the absolute path. In the build process I am specifying the full path of all the libraries instead of depending on LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Also I am using the full path of the toolchains instead of relying on PATH.